# If $X$ is $T_1$ then there exist $x_0\in X$ such that $\{x_0\}=\bigcap\mathcal{B}(x)$ for some local basis $\mathcal{B}(x)$ of $x$.

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement**
>
> If $X$ is a $T_1$ space then there exist $x_0\in X$ that has a local basis $\mathcal{B}(x_0)$ such that $\{x_0\}=\bigcap\mathcal{B}(x_0)$.
>
> *Proof*. So let be $X$ a $T_1$ space and we suppose that for any $x\in X$ it follows that $\{x\}\neq\bigcap{B}(x)$, for any local basis $\mathcal{B}(x)$: so there exist $y\neq x$ such that $y\in\bigcap\{B(x)\}$ and so this means that the nhood sistem of $x$ is the same of $y$, that is $\mathcal{V}(x)=\mathcal{V}(y)$; so it follows that if $U$ is an open set that contain $x$ then $U$ contain even $y$ and this is impossible if $X$ is $T_1$.

So is the proof correct? if not, how to prove the statement? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: In fact, the sub-stament is true for every $x ∈ X$, and the original statement is not true for $X = ∅$. Also you can formulate the proof more directly: let $x ∈ X$ be given, and put $\mathcal{B}(x) := \mathcal{V}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just state that $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$ iff

$$\forall x \in X: \bigcap\{O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O\}=\{x\}$$

The forward implication: in the identity the right to left inclusion is obvious, and if $y \neq x$, note that $O = X\setminus\{y\}$ is one set in the intersection, so $y \notin \bigcap\{O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O\}$, which shows the other inclusion. The reverse implication is similar.

No need for local bases or a specific point $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

That indirect proof, if correct, is hard to follow.
Here is a direct proof,  As x is T$_1$,
for all y /= x, exists U in B(x) with y not in B(x).
Thus x in $\cap$B(x) subset {x}.  QED